# How optimize some code by making array?

Tags: java, android

in my code i have a `for` that it repeat 100 time for `{lg0 , lg1 , samsong0 ,...}`
`{lg0 , lg1 , samsong0 ,...}` is list of some class that they have static List

```
for (int i = 0;i < lg0.brandStringList.length ; i++ )
{
    MobileInformation mobile = new MobileInformation();

    mobile.Alert_types = lg0.Alert_typesStringList[i];
    .
    .
    .
    mobile.Video = lg0.VideoStringList[i];          
}
```

one way for Solving problem is writting 100 `for` that is not good way.
for ex:
if i have {lg0 , lg1} i must write below code

```
for (int i = 0;i < lg0.brandStringList.length ; i++ )
{
    MobileInformation mobile = new MobileInformation();

    mobile.Alert_types = lg0.Alert_typesStringList[i];
    .
    .
    .
    mobile.Video = lg0.VideoStringList[i];          
}

for (int i = 0;i < lg1.brandStringList.length ; i++ )
{
    MobileInformation mobile = new MobileInformation();

    mobile.Alert_types = lg1.Alert_typesStringList[i];
    .
    .
    .
    mobile.Video = lg1.VideoStringList[i];          
}
```

Question
How i can make a List for all Class and optimize above code by using it.

Comment: so you have 100 classes that all define the same properties (`brandStringList `, `Alert_typesStringList`, `VideoStringList`...)?

Comment: I understand why you would want to change that design. Can you put all values in only one class? From the code posted, I don't understand the need to separate `lg1`, `lg0` ...

Comment: My data is big that exist in all class . so if i put them in one class   size of file will be big. So i get error limited size file eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a base class or interface which exposes the common methods/fields you need, then make a list of the base class and iterate through the components within the class:

```
public class BaseInfoClass {
    public static brandStringList[];
    public static Alert_typesStringList[];
    public static VideoStringList[];
}

private LinkedList<BaseInfoClass> mAllInfo;  //  Init this as you need with lg0, etc.

public void whateverMethod() {
    for (BaseInfoClass curClass : mAllInfo) {
        for (int i = 0; i < curClass.brandStringList.length; i)) {
            MobileInformation newInfo = new MobileInformation();
            mobile.Alert_types = curClass.Alert_typesStringList[i];
            .
            .
            .
            mobile.Video = curClass.VideoStringList[i];          
        }
    }
}
```